# Ensure my javascript is the last thing executed when dom is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, detect, ready

I am working on a page where javascript from various sources is being executed .

I want to ensure my custom js is only executed AFTER everthing else has been done .

The "other" js is call on various events like clicking some buttons etc ..all of which change/alter the Dom in some way .I want to detect in my custom js when this DOM change is complete I want to do something(which may also change the DOM but thats fine as it may result into execting my js twice which i can afford ) But the main question is how to I know that the other js is done with the DOM ?

Comment: do you try use $(document).ready function or $(function(){ // logic });

Comment: he isnt wanting dom readiness he is wanting a `ondomchanged` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Answer (score 3):

You can put your code inside [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Code goes here
});
```

If you want to run code once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready, then use:

```
$( window ).load(function() { 
    // Code goes here 
})
```

Comment: these handler would only work (correct me if i am wrong) when the DOM is ready for the first form load .My requirement is as @Patrick Evans said is ondomchanged event which can be triggered anytime on the page I need to capute that and re run my code every time that happens .

Comment: @user2319373 I think there's no way you can achieve it....